# How to access edge dimensions in pythonocc?

Tags: python, step, pythonocc

I'm trying to use PythonOCC to read in wireframe data (see [this link](https://cad.onshape.com/documents/84d7d41e90357905e69d675b/w/70256b1d6d6272608a109cb9/e/1dd5be033460c35e01d4ac53)) that is in IGES or STEP format, for eventual use in building a FE beam-element model.

Where in PythonOCC can I actually extract properties about edges and curves? I've built this sample that prints out all vertices in a file:

```
from OCC.Extend.DataExchange import read_iges_file
from OCC.Core.TopExp import (TopExp_Explorer,
                        topexp_MapShapesAndAncestors,
                        topexp_FirstVertex,
                        topexp_LastVertex)
from OCC.Core.TopAbs import *
from OCC.Core.TopoDS import TopoDS_Shape, topods
from OCC.Core.BRep import BRep_Tool, BRep_Tool_Pnt, BRep_Tool_IsGeometric, BRep_Tool_Parameter, BRep_Tool_Curve
from OCC.Core.BRepAdaptor import BRepAdaptor_Curve
from OCC.Core.GeomTools import GeomTools_CurveSet

shape = read_iges_file('tubes.iges')

topExp = TopExp_Explorer()
topExp.Init(shape, TopAbs_EDGE)

def print_vertex(va):
    print(BRep_Tool().Pnt(va).Coord(1), BRep_Tool().Pnt(va).Coord(2), BRep_Tool().Pnt(va).Coord(3))

while topExp.More():
    edge = topExp.Current()
    first, last = topexp_FirstVertex(edge), topexp_LastVertex(edge)
    curv = BRepAdaptor_Curve(edge).Curve()
    print_vertex(first)
    print_vertex(last)
    
    topExp.Next()
    print()
```

That said, what I really want is to know if a curve is a line versus an arc, and if it's an arc, what the centerpoint and radius are.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to do something similar. If this can be useful, I am using the following snippet to get the type of a Curve and then extracting vertices:

```
    # given and Edge edge
    curv = BRepAdaptor_Curve(edge).Curve()
    a = 0.0
    b = 0.0
    [curve_handle, a, b] = OCC.BRep.BRep_Tool.Curve(edge)
    print(curve_handle.GetObject().DynamicType().GetObject().Name())
    initial_point = OCC.gp.gp_Pnt()
    final_point = OCC.gp.gp_Pnt()
    
    curve_handle.GetObject().D0(a, initial_point)
    curve_handle.GetObject().D0(b, final_point)
    
    print(f'init: ({initial_point.X()}, {initial_point.Y()}), end ({final_point.X()}, {final_point.Y()})')
```